# Do gittin have to be written in Hebrew

Tags: halacha, language, divorce, legal-documents, even-haezer

According to Halacha, do  gittin (divorce documents) have to be written in Hebrew? Or can they be written in other languages and be valid? If it can’t be any language, is it still valid if written in a non Hebrew language (like  Sefer torahs can be written in Greek)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A *get* can in theory be written in any single language, but longstanding practice is to write it in (largely) Aramaic ([EH 126:1](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%95_%D7%90)).

Comment: I assume you know the taz there who calls it lashon hatalmudim.